# Escape Swiper even when match is required

Tags: completion, swiper

Swiper automatically moves to the next location that matches your current input. You can press RET to return to the main buffer when the search is successful.

When you type in a word that does not exist, Swiper remains at the last location where a match was found. Then, when you press RET, Swiper says "match required" and does not return to the buffer. It seems that the only options are to cancel (C-g, which returns to the position before calling Swiper) or to modify the input in the minibuffer.

Is it possible to by-pass the "matching requirement" and to return to the buffer at the location selected by Swiper, even when there is no more matching? Swiper behavior is very annoying and slow (because of the cancelling of the search or the changing of the input search), when you just mistyped or went too restrictive in the search.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `(setq swiper-stay-on-quit t)`.

When you hit C-g you'll be redirected to the location selected by swiper.